# AWS IAM policy - How to check for multiple Tags as OR condition

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to make a or condition in my IAM users but i don't know why it's not working...

I want two make a allow condition like this:

```
 if ec2:ResourceTag/User == "${aws:username}" || ec2:ResourceTag/Group == "Dev"
```

I have try many things but all not works...

```
"StringEquals": {
  "ec2:ResourceTag/User": "${aws:username}",
  "ec2:ResourceTag/Group": "Dev"
}
---
"ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
  "ec2:ResourceTag/User": "${aws:username}",
  "ec2:ResourceTag/Group": "Dev"
}
```

EDIT ---

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
      "ec2:StartInstances",
      "ec2:StopInstances",
      "ec2:RebootInstances",
      "ec2:TerminateInstances"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
      "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/User": "${aws:username}",
          "ec2:ResourceTag/Group": "Developers"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: On what type of resource are you adding this condition? Can you show us an example of a full policy you are wanting to implement?

Comment: An EC2, i have edited my post.

Comment: I also need to solve this, but for `secretsmanager:ResourceTag` instead. It boils down to how it is possible to combine `ForAnyValue` with attributes with distinct values AND keys.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution definitely works to check for distinct `ResourceTag` attributes with different values as OR condition. You can always put them into separate statements. Which is of course inconvenient:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "sid1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [ ... ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:...",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/mytag": "myvalue"
            }
        }
      },
      {
        "Sid": "sid2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [ same as in sid1 ],
        "Resource": "same as in sid1",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/myothertag": "myothervalue"
            }
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

I'm not aware of a solution which works with a single statement. If there is then it is not documented in AWS docs.